# Export reactive property directly vs toRef wrap

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I'm creating my Vue 2 "store" using the new composition API (https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api). I would like to expose a subset of my state.

What is the correct approach to maintain reactivity with a reference to the source property?

```
const state = reactive({
  somethingInternal: '',
  name: ''
})

// is this enough?
export const name = state.name
// or do I need to do this?
export const name = toRef(state, 'name')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `toRef` to maintain reactivity.

This only exports a string literal:

```
export const name = state.name
```

But this preserves the connection to the reactive property:

```
export const name = toRef(state, 'name')
```

If you import `state` and both exports of `name` all into another module, then change `state.name`, the change will be reflected in the `toRef` export but not the literal.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any syntactic sugar that allows me to export it as "name" without defining a variable for it? The closest I can think of is `...toRefs(state)` but that would add all properties

Comment: You're welcome.  If I understand your followup Q correctly, you could export some  other object which has properties with `toRef` values:   `export const obj = { name: toRef(state, 'name')  }`

Comment: Right, but I still have to define the "name" key, that's what I would like to avoid doing manually since there is no validation that it'd match the actual state property name

Comment: So you want a dynamic property name?  Yeah you can do that with [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):   `export const obj = { [propName]: toRef(state, propName) }`.  Never tried that with an export name (i.e. without wrapping it in `obj`) but you can give it a shot.